# Issue with changing Gridview cell color depending on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change the cell color of the gridview, if DOT < today's date.  My issue is that it changes to red all the rows for the DOT column even though DOT column > today's date.
[image]

here is my code

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound_gvTest(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {

            Label lblDOT = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("DOT");
            DateTime DOTDate = DateTime.Parse(lblDOT.Text);
            if (DOTDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
              //e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
              gvDriverStatus.Columns[3].ItemStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }


          }
        }
```

Comment: you need to change the color for the e.Row.Cell[3] instead of the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
gvDriverStatus.Columns[3].ItemStyle.ForeColor = ...
```

will change the color of the whole column. To change only the cell color, use:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = ...
```